# How to Redirect from PHP, receiving an XMLHttp POST request

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, redirect

My questions is about redirection from `PHP`. I know that we can redirect from a php page to another page by nust using

```
header("Location: ".$redirectURL);
```

In my case, one `php` file receives a XMLHttp POST request, done using javascript in front-end. It manipulates some data in it, and now sets a cookie and then i want to redirect to another page. All pages are in same domain only.

I want to move to the other page, from PHP. Can i do this? Any methods for these?

edit:

Situation is like this, from a login page, i will post the username &password to one php page, where its validated. From validation its understood if the user belongs to a server in some other region(We use a regional divisioning), i will redirect him to that servers login page, but with a cookie set. So that login page understands he's already logged in, and open his homepage.

Thanks for Help :)

Comment: why do you want to redirect from that page? is there some more processing that requries the redirection for that request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

client : ajax client which do request
serverphp : php file which executing ajax request

#### 1. Redirect client to another page

`serverphp` return an address `client` listener redirect client's browser

#### 2. Redirect serverphp to another page

You can do a request to `first.php` then redirect it to `second.php` and ajax will get answer from `second.php`

Answer (score 3):

You can return URL and do window.location.href assignment in your ajax handler. I think it is the simplest way.

*Following update in question*: you should remember that you can set cookies for some domain or for subdomains, so, if your regional servers is allocated on completely different domains (for example, myserver.com, myserver.co.uk, myserver.ru) - they will not recognize your cookie and you need some other way to transmit that user is logged in. (One time key in shared storage may be solution)

Comment: Assuming your post update, it is still the most simple way :)